# How can I move my select statement from my for loop (trigger)

Tags: trigger

Hi i have a trigger in my custom object and it hit governor limit due to select statment in my for loop. now i would like to move my statement out. can anyone help? here is my trigger:

```
trigger CalculateMorgage on Property__c (before insert) 
{
    for(Property__c pp: Trigger.new)
    {       
        List <House_Type__c> ht = [SELECT ID, Property_Type__c  FROM House_Type__c WHERE Range__c =: pp.range__c and Quantity__c =: pp.p_quantity__c];

        if(!ht.isempty())
        {
            for(House_Type__c htt : ht)
            {
                pp.type__c = htt.Property_Type__c ;
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

in my House_Type__c object it is something like this:

```
Range__c    Quantity__c     Property_Type__c
R_10            10              AC01
R_10            50              AC02
R_10            500             AC03
```

so if my quantity is 25 it will return AC02 & AC03 but i need only AC02

Comment: What are the field types for Range__c and Quantity__c?

Comment: Range__c is text while Quantity__c is number

Comment: And what happens if there are multiple house types found for the same property? Which one do you apply?

Comment: basically it wont return multiple house type. with my 'Range__c =: pp.range__c and Quantity__c =: pp.p_quantity__c' it will always return 1 result only. i hit limit is because i do data import

Answer (score 4):

See below the bulkified version of your trigger. Not sure if it's going to work as I typed it on the fly and never compiled but you can fix it up and get the idea based on my comments:

```
trigger CalculateMorgage on Property__c (before insert) 
{
    Set <String> ranges = new Set <String> (); // Set of all ranges from every property in this trigger
    Set <Integer> quantities = new Set <Integer> (); // Set of all quantities from every property in this trigger
    Map <String, Property__c> rangeQuantityProperty = new Map <String, Property__c> (); // Map of concatenated string of range + quantity for the property as a key, and the actual property record as a value

    for(Property__c pp : Trigger.new)
    {
        // For each property in this trigger populate the sets of ranges and quantities and also map the property record to it's Range + Quantity string
        ranges.add(pp.Range__c);
        quantities.add(pp.P_Quantity__c);
        rangeQuantityProperty.put(pp.Range__c + pp.P_Quantity__c, pp);
    }

    // Get all house types in the system that have range that is in the set of ranges above and quantity that is in the set of quantities above
    for (House_Type__c houseType : [SELECT ID, Property_Type__c, Range__c, Quantity__c FROM House_Type__c WHERE Range__c IN :ranges and Quantity__c IN :quantities])
    {
        // Generate concatenated string for the house type range + quantity
        String rangeQuantity = houseType.Range__c + houseType.Quantity__c;

        // Check if we have this range + quantity in the map as a key (if there is a matching property record with the same values)
        if (rangeQuantityProperty.get(rangeQuantity) != null)
        {
            // if there is, then get that record from the map and set the Type__c to this current house type property type
            rangeQuantityProperty.get(rangeQuantity).Type__c = houseType.Property_Type__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that's an excellent trigger. For similar scenarios to the OP, (two fields uniquely identify an object), I've found creating a formula field can simplify the logic, or alternatively a text field that's set in a before trigger for that object, `House_Type__c` in this instance.

Comment: Yeh good point Ralph. I'd do the formula field too in this case!

Comment: hi, we have modify our logic..now that the select statement will return more than 1 result. so i have change my select statement to > '[SELECT ID, Property_Type__c, Range__c, Quantity__c FROM House_Type__c WHERE Range__c IN :ranges and Quantity__c >= :quantities order by Property_Type__c Limit 1]' and now my map wouldnt work because the keyset is different. any idea?

Comment: You can't limit the number of SOQL rows to 1 because now you're getting ALL targeted House Types. If you have more than 1 record in the system with the same Range + Quantity, then it's bad data modelling issue, you'll need to revisit that and maybe model it differently or add another 3rd parameter that will make those combinations unique so that you always have 1 key-value pair.

Comment: thanks for the advice. basically in my House_Type__c object is something like this:

Range__c         Quantity__c       Property_Type__c
R_10                10                 AC01
R_10                50                 AC02
R_10                100                AC03

so if my parameter quantity is 25, with my select statement it will return AC02 & AC03 so i limit 1 because AC02 is what i want. is that alright with my logic?

Comment: No, based on your updated question, whatever is specified on the property it will find exactly one match in your system if you don't have duplicates. Example: Property range is R_10 and p_quantity__c is 10 - it will return house types that have R_10 and 10 accordingly. Both values must match, which is the key in the map "R_1010". If you have multiple house types that have range 10 and quantity 10, then that might be an issue

Comment: hi Bachovski, thanks for the advice again. Actually the Quantity__c up there is a range, for example quantity 10 so if my parameter is within 0-10 and range = R_10 then i should get AC01. and 11-50 is another range, so if my parameter is 25 and range = R_10 then i should get AC02. my passed in parameters is not fixed to my Quantity__c, it will be within a range

Comment: That's a completely new requirement compared to your original question. Please ask that as another question.

Comment: Can we close this thread?